# changing state of an LED using a pushbutton leads to unstable result

Tags: arduino-uno, led, button

I am trying to run this code:

```cpp
const int buttonPin = 7;     
const int ledPin13 =  13;      

int buttonState = 0;         
int lastButtonState = buttonState;
bool flag = true;

void setup() {
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin13, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);


  if (buttonState = HIGH && lastButtonState != buttonState) {
    flag = !flag;
    if (flag){
      digitalWrite(ledPin13, LOW);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(ledPin13, HIGH);
    }
  }
}
```

on this SimulIDE model:

```xml
<circuit reactStep="50" animate="0" type="simulide_0.1" noLinStep="10" noLinAcc="5" speed="1000000">

Node-16: 
<item labelrot="0" y="-204" valLabRot="0" valLabelx="0" valLabely="0" hflip="1" vflip="1" x="-220" labelx="-16" labely="-24" Show_id="false" objectName="Node-16" itemtype="Node" id="Node-16" rotation="0"/>

Arduino Uno-4: 
<item hflip="1" Show_id="true" valLabely="0" itemtype="Arduino" vflip="1" labelx="0" objectName="Arduino Uno-4" labely="-20" y="-244" Ser_Port="false" labelrot="0" rotation="0" Program="../../Google Drive/Active projects/SRL/Students/Damian2019/Simulation/20190409/noDelay_20190409/noDelay_20190409.ino.standard.hex" Ser_Monitor="false" id="Arduino Uno-4" valLabelx="0" Mhz="16" valLabRot="0" x="-148"/>

Resistor-3: 
<item Unit=" O" hflip="1" Show_id="false" valLabely="6" itemtype="Resistor" Show_res="true" vflip="1" labelx="-12" objectName="Resistor-3" labely="-24" y="-164" labelrot="0" rotation="-90" Resistance="100" id="Resistor-3" valLabelx="-16" valLabRot="0" x="-220"/>

Push-2: 
<item labelrot="0" y="-308" valLabRot="0" valLabelx="0" valLabely="0" hflip="1" vflip="1" x="-100" labelx="-16" labely="-24" Show_id="false" objectName="Push-2" itemtype="Push" id="Push-2" rotation="0"/>

Connector-5: 
<item hflip="1" Show_id="false" valLabely="0" itemtype="Connector" vflip="1" startpinid="Resistor-3-lPin" labelx="-16" objectName="Connector-5" labely="-24" y="-148" endpinid="Arduino Uno-4-GND0" enodeid="Circ_eNode-6" labelrot="0" pointList="-220,-148,-220,-108,-140,-108" rotation="0" id="Connector-5" valLabelx="0" valLabRot="0" x="-220"/>

Connector-11: 
<item hflip="1" Show_id="false" valLabely="0" itemtype="Connector" vflip="1" startpinid="Push-2-rnod" labelx="-16" objectName="Connector-11" labely="-24" y="-308" endpinid="Arduino Uno-4-V5V" enodeid="Circ_eNode-12" labelrot="0" pointList="-84,-308,44,-308,44,-148,4,-148" rotation="0" id="Connector-11" valLabelx="0" valLabRot="0" x="-84"/>

Connector-9: 
<item hflip="1" Show_id="false" valLabely="0" itemtype="Connector" vflip="1" startpinid="Push-2-lnod" labelx="-16" objectName="Connector-9" labely="-24" y="-308" endpinid="Node-16-0" enodeid="enode-15" labelrot="0" pointList="-116,-308,-220,-308,-220,-204" rotation="0" id="Connector-9" valLabelx="0" valLabRot="0" x="-116"/>

Connector-15: 
<item hflip="1" Show_id="false" valLabely="0" itemtype="Connector" vflip="1" startpinid="Arduino Uno-4-PD7" labelx="-16" objectName="Connector-15" labely="-24" y="-172" endpinid="Node-16-1" enodeid="enode-15" labelrot="0" pointList="-140,-172,-172,-172,-172,-204,-220,-204" rotation="0" id="Connector-15" valLabelx="0" valLabRot="0" x="-140"/>

Connector-17: 
<item hflip="1" Show_id="false" valLabely="0" itemtype="Connector" vflip="1" startpinid="Node-16-2" labelx="-16" objectName="Connector-17" labely="-24" y="-204" endpinid="Resistor-3-rPin" enodeid="enode-15" labelrot="0" pointList="-220,-204,-220,-180" rotation="0" id="Connector-17" valLabelx="0" valLabRot="0" x="-220"/>

PlotterWidget-13: 
<item modal="false" childrenRect="" normalGeometry="" baseSize="" geometry="" sizeIncrement="" windowOpacity="1" windowModified="false" enabled="true" maximumSize="" childrenRegion="" maximumHeight="200" inputMethodHints="0" mouseTracking="false" minimumSize="" frameGeometry="" sizeHint="" windowIconText="" locale="" minimumSizeHint="" height="200" isActiveWindow="true" x="0" accessibleName="" layoutDirection="0" autoFillBackground="false" width="200" windowFilePath="" windowModality="0" maximized="false" sizePolicy="" MinVolt="-500" fullScreen="false" windowTitle="" windowIcon="" maximumWidth="1000" objectName="PlotterWidget-13" toolTip="" toolTipDuration="-1" focus="false" MaxVolt="500" palette="" font="MS Shell Dlg 2,8.25,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0" whatsThis="" pos="" minimumWidth="200" minimumHeight="200" size="" focusPolicy="0" itemtype="Plotter" updatesEnabled="true" accessibleDescription="" y="0" rect="" frameSize="" minimized="false" acceptDrops="false" styleSheet="" cursor="" visible="false" statusTip="" contextMenuPolicy="1"/>

SerialPortWidget-14: 
<item modal="false" childrenRect="" normalGeometry="" SettingsProp="COM1,0,3,0,0,0" baseSize="" geometry="" sizeIncrement="" windowOpacity="1" windowModified="false" enabled="true" maximumSize="" childrenRegion="" maximumHeight="170" inputMethodHints="0" mouseTracking="false" minimumSize="" frameGeometry="" sizeHint="" windowIconText="" locale="" minimumSizeHint="" height="141" isActiveWindow="true" x="0" accessibleName="" layoutDirection="0" autoFillBackground="false" width="313" windowFilePath="" windowModality="0" maximized="false" sizePolicy="" fullScreen="false" windowTitle="Settings" windowIcon="" maximumWidth="450" objectName="SerialPortWidget-14" toolTip="" toolTipDuration="-1" focus="false" palette="" font="MS Shell Dlg 2,8.25,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0" whatsThis="" pos="" minimumWidth="0" minimumHeight="0" size="" focusPolicy="0" itemtype="SerialPort" updatesEnabled="true" accessibleDescription="" y="0" rect="" frameSize="" minimized="false" acceptDrops="false" styleSheet="" cursor="" visible="false" statusTip="" contextMenuPolicy="1"/>

</circuit>
```

and I expect the LED to be turned on-off everytime I push the button, however the result is unstable:

I would appreciate if you could help me know if there is something wrong with my code or circuit and I should expect the same behavior on an actual hardware, or this is a simulation issue?

**P.S.1.** All file can also be downloaded from [here](https://we.tl/t-JRlKclqjBf).

**P.S.2.** I'm using [this example from Arduino.org website](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/button).

**P.S.3.** I also tried using an actual Arduino, also implementing the suggestions below. However the issue is not resolved. You may see the video [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/p8PTzLZjDotrimyAA).

Comment: You need the state-change-detection: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StateChangeDetection

Answer (score 2):

Certain Changes in your code:

```
const int buttonPin = 7;     
const int ledPin13 =  13;      

int buttonState = 0;         
int lastButtonState = buttonState;
bool flag = true;

void setup() {
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin13, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);


  if (buttonState == HIGH && lastButtonState != buttonState) {
    lastButtonState = buttonState;
    flag =!flag;
    if (flag){
      digitalWrite(ledPin13, LOW);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(ledPin13, HIGH);
    }
  }
}
```

Secondly your hardware model is not good.
ANODE of LED must be connected to PIN13 and Cathode to GND. And switch must be placed between 3.3 V and Pin7 only.
In your model by closing switch you are shorting 3.3V and GND. If you had provided an external pullup then you should use at minimum a 4.7K resistor value. 100ohm never works.

I don't have software for Design so I used Paint and made a sketch for you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsPSP8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: ah my bad the `lastButtonState = buttonState;` was in the actual code but I dropped it accidentally in the example. would you be kind to draw the correct circuit? I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: The OP is using 5V, not 3.3v. And how is his circuit's switch shorting 3.3V/5V to ground? If pin7 were an output, and LOW, it would be a low resistance path to ground. It might be a good idea to put a 1K resistor on Pin7.

Comment: In your diagram, you need a current-limiting resistor on the LED or it will both draw too much current from pin13 and over-drive the LED (But I think the OP is using the built-in LED on pin 13 rather than adding an external LED.)

Comment: There's still a problem in the code: lastButtonState will always be HIGH, because it is inside the if(buttonState == HIGH) block.

Answer (score 2):

I identify a few problems here:

- The 100 Ohm pulldown resistor for the button is way too low. 1 kOhm to 100 kOhm is typically used here.
- `if( buttonState = HIGH )` does not *compare*, it *assigns* buttonState to HIGH (overwriting the value read with `digitalRead(buttonPin)`). Use the compare-for-equality operator `==` here, otherwise the `if` just checks if buttonState has been assigned a "truthlike" value (incidentally, HIGH is one of them).
- As others have already commented, lastButtonState must be set somewhere after the `if`-block!

Since many Arduinos do have pullup resistors built in, I'd say: drop the resistor completely, instead initialize the button input pin (7) to use its built-in pullup resistor ... this will invert the logic and you'll have to connect the button between pin 7 and GND (i.e. swapping button and resistor), though:

```
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

This will have the same result as if you replaced the 100 Ohm resistor with a 20 kOhm resistor after swapping button and resistor -- but that resistor is now inside the Arduino. (Take care if you use "Arduino-compatible" boards; sometimes they lack the pullup resistors or have them fixed!).

There still is one problem: bouncing. Pressing a mechanical button leads to the contacts inside the button to bounce a bit against each other, leading to a *very* fast HIGH-LOW-HIGH-LOW-etc signal before it settles on the target state. You can alleviate this a bit by adding a `delay(5)` at the end of your `loop()`, but using a button library (e.g. [Button](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/button), available in the Arduino IDE Library Manager) that debounces the signal will lead to better results most of the time.

This will lead to this code (also including the ternary operator hint by Michel Keijzers):

```
const int buttonPin = 7;     
const int ledPin13 =  13;      

int buttonState = 0;         
int lastButtonState = buttonState;
bool flag = true;

void setup() {
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin13, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (buttonState == LOW && lastButtonState != buttonState) {
    flag = !flag;
    digitalWrite(ledPin13, flag ? LOW : HIGH);
  }

  lastButtonState = buttonState;
  delay(5);
}
```

This should do the trick (I didn't try it, though).

Comment: OMG how could I make such a mistake!!! Thanks for pointing it out. one issue you should consider is that Arduino uno doesn't have `INPUT_PULLDOWN`. Apparently only Zero has this? I get the error `INPUT_PULLDOWN was not declared in this scope`

Comment: ok. it seems the `pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLDOWN);` is equivalent of `pinMode(pin, INPUT); digitalWrite(pin, LOW);` and `pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);` is `pinMode(pin, INPUT); digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);` and that syntax doesn't work properly on some versions of Arduino IDE.

Comment: @Foad You're right, according to https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins INPUT_PULLDOWN seems to be rather seldom... but INPUT_PULLUP should work. Using this would invert the logic on the button pin, though. I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: could you be kind to 1. draw the circuit using the pullup resistor 2. point me a good button library? thanks again.

Comment: @Foad I added a link to the most simple button library with debouncing from the Arduino IDE Library Manager; documentation is on its github page. Drawing the circuit must have to wait until I'm back home.

Answer (score 1):

There are already great answers, but I also found out about the interrupt functionality:

```cpp
const byte ledPin = 13;
const byte interruptPin = 2;
volatile byte state = LOW;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), blink, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, state);
}

void blink() {
  state = !state;
}
```

some point:

- no matter using interrupt or the methods above tho process will not achieve stable / deterministic result. The issue lies in the hardware of the push-button and there will be fluctuations which can be interpreted by the MCU. One way to alleviate is to use delay.
- The
- `attachInterrupt` has four modes `LOW`, `Change`, `FALLING` and `RISING`. The `FALLING` and `RISING` modes are the one to be used. the other two also lead to very unpredictable result.
- Only pins `1` and `2` can be used for interrupts.
- There is also the option to mix the two methods which you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/b1e9820632d953705fcb49fc75c1f4fb), but I'm not sure if it will improve the stability.

I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXDgHuUKGqU) and information on [this page](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment (but could not use text alignment in a comment):

Instead of

```
if (flag){
  digitalWrite(ledPin13, LOW);
} else {
  digitalWrite(ledPin13, HIGH);
}
```

You can use:

```
digitalWrite(ledPin13, flag ? LOW : HIGH);
```

(It is functionally 100% equal though).

Comment: nice. I did not know we have ternary operator also here On Arduino language.

Comment: Actually the Arduino IDE is very similar to C++. The ternary operator is from the C language.

Comment: Very nice that Arduino language is compliant with the common C/C++ compilers.

Comment: Also several libraries are written in C++ (so you can use OO/classes); however some features are better to skip (like the Boost library if it works at all), because of dynamic memory management versus having only a few KB SRAM available.

Comment: I do not understand why they down voted you. I appreciate your support anyway.

Comment: Probably because it should be a comment (but code alignment is only possible inside an answer).

Comment: @Foad You could think of the Arduino sketch file as a part of a standard C/C++ file. Prior to compiling, the sketch is just inserted into the main file of a standard GCC build tree, included library files and hardware libraries are just copied next to it. Then gcc takes over; you could see its output if you enable verbose compiling in the Arduino IDE preferences.

Comment: @jsotola basically `int 0, 1`, `bool false, true` and `LOW, HIGH` are the same?

Comment: @orithena is it avr-gcc behind the scene?

Comment: @Foad Which gcc exactly is used depends on the board selected (for my boards, it's gcc-xtensa, but I only use ESP8266 boards ^^). Verbose compile output will show the exact compiler binary that is used.

Comment: @orithena how/where do I set the `verbos` option?

Comment: @jsotola it could be dangerous to assume values for LOW and HIGH, what if ST decides LOW is 25 and HIGH is 38? Not likely, but I wouldn't want my code to be depending on the values of LOW and HIGH.

Comment: @Foad See the screenshot at https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Preferences, "Show verbose output during [x] compilation".